# Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out - for Azure Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, azure

I have created postgres DB on the Azure Server, but somehow my Dbeaver client and Spring Boot App unable to connect and giving below error.

[image]

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.example.jdbc.JdbcWithAzurePostgresServerApplication.main(JdbcWithAzurePostgresServerApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have added your IP address to the Postgres database firewall rule, as this might be the reason for a connection timeout error. To add your IP address, go to the server networking tab and add the IP as shown below:

[image]